# Do all the letters in Sta"m need to be the same "baseline" height?

Tags: tefilin, sefer-torah, safrus, mezuzah

I know that prior to writing a column in a Sefer Torah, a Sofer "scores" the parchment to mark the rows. I am also aware that certain letters have "risers" and "descenders" (e.g. a final nun has a descender and lamed has an ascender.) Similarly, there are a number of intentionally tiny (*ze'ira*) or large (*Rabbati*) letters.

Aside from these situations, must a sofer write each letter using the same "baseline" height when going across the row? Must the bottom "baseline" of each letter be the same across the row, or can they "jump around"? I've occasionally seen *mezuzot* and tefillin parchments having "curvy" rows, so I'm curious if this allowed? Are there different restrictions on this between a Torah and tefillin / mezuzot, perhaps?

Comment: It's likely the "curvy" mezuzos and tefillin parshiyos are not kosher.

Comment: @ezra Very possible. That's implied in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The scores on the parchment are called *sirtut* and are mandatory on a sefer Torah ([SA OC 32:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.32.6?lang=bi)) and mezuza but not on tefillin ([Hilchot Mezuza 1:12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925417/jewish/Tefillin-Mezuzah-and-Sefer-Torah-Chapter-One.htm)). They help to write straight. It doesn't mean however that the letters have to be the same size. **The Rambam** in [Hilchot Tefillin, Mezuzah and Sefer Torah](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925369/jewish/Tefillin-Mezuzah-and-Sefer-Torah.htm) **does NOT mention that the letters have to be of the same size**. The closest he gets ([7:5](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925429/jewish/Tefillin-Mezuzah-and-Sefer-Torah-Chapter-Seven.htm)) is to write that

> One should not reduce the size of a letter in order to leave the
>   proper amount of space between one passage and another.

and in [7:9](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925429/jewish/Tefillin-Mezuzah-and-Sefer-Torah-Chapter-Seven.htm) he doesn't mention equal letter size as a requirement (same in [10:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925432/jewish/Tefillin-Mezuzah-and-Sefer-Torah-Chapter-Ten.htm))

> All the above matters were mentioned only because this is the most
>   perfect way of performing the mitzvah. Should one, however, alter the
>   structure [of a scroll from that] mentioned above or not be precise
>   regarding the placement of the crowns, [the scroll is acceptable] if
>   all the letters were written as they should be.
>
> [Similarly,] if one wrote the lines closer together, separated them
>   further, lengthened them, or shortened them, the scroll is acceptable,
>   provided one letter does not touch another, no letters are omitted,
>   extra letters are not added, the shape of even a single letter is not
>   altered, and the [form of the passages, whether] p'tuchah or s'tumah,
>   is not changed.

**So equal size does not appear to be a requirement of a kosher Torah scroll** and, in practice, they will sometimes not be the same size across a whole sefer Torah. However a more *mehudar* (beautiful) parchment will have as little difference as possible across letters.

---

R Reuvain Mendlowitz in his book [Inside Stam](http://amzn.com/1600912133) explicitly mentions this (pp. 36-37) where he describes a sofer who changed his mind after writing 20 columns of a sefer Torah and wrote bigger letters for the rest of it as he felt they enhanced the beauty of the writing.

Experts who saw the Sefer Torah felt that this fell into the category of "normal" changes in letter size. Nevertheless the sofer felt that the change in letter size was not fitting for a high-quality Sefer Torah and, on his own initiative, offered to rewrite the first twenty columns (half a month's work) free of charge!

---

[R Yerachmiel Askotzky](http://www.stam.net/about_me.aspx) in his book [Tefillin and Mezuzos](http://a.co/gZZ3cz8) writes

> (p. 135) Things which affect a pair of tefillin's aesthetic beauty
>   include ... writing that is not uniform in width, thickness, height or
>   style.

Note that he speaks of beauty, not halachic permissibility.

Later (p. 136-137) he writes

> If the writing is not in a straight, horizontal line, the parchment is
>   *passul* and irreparable according to all *poskim*. Letters that are written very slightly below the *sirtut* are acceptable. If there is
>   writing clearly below the *sirtut*, some *poskim* say it is still
>   kosher as long as the writing is straight. According to other
>   *poskim*, writing below the *sirtut* will make a parchment *passul*. [...] If the writing is wavy or on an angle, it is *passul* and irreparable.

**That would make the "curvy rows" very challenging halachically** but, of course, they should be shown to an expert before deciding anything.

Comment: +1 It seems that I get a few interesting book ideas from you! If you can find something that addresses the "curvy line" issue, please edit this into your answer.

Comment: @DanF I found something on curvy - see end of my answer. If relevant I have R Askotzky email - I found him very approachable when I had detailed questions

Comment: "According to other poskim, writing below the sirtut will make a parchment passul." That is a little remarkable to me. Did any of the Tur, Beis Yosef, Shulchan Oruch, Rema, Nosei Keilim, Shulchan Aruch Harav, Mishnah Berurah, Aruch Hashulchan, Keset Hasofer say anything about this at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See Orach Chayim 32:6, especially the Biur Halacha.

Comment: Hi Yitzhak. A rather belated welcome to MY, as I don't think you have answered any of my questions, before. For, mainly, the benefit of the many readers that aren't competent in Hebrew, would you mind summarizing the main points? Also, as I've asked a few questions, please specify what "Yes" applies to?

Comment: Nice headshot, Yitzchak !

Comment: You might want to use Sefaria to point readers in the right direction. OC with translation is here https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.32.6?lang=bi and the Biur Halacha is here https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.32.6?lang=bi&p2=Biur_Halacha.32.6.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en

Comment: "Yes" what? He asked several questions, and a Yes to some implies a No to others.

Comment: Also, maybe I'm missing it, but I don't see where the _Beur Halacha_ discusses writing different-height letters in the same line.

Comment: Your answer would be be much improved if you summarized the contents of your sources, or, at the very least, linked them to a site for convenience.